# Two realms in same application with Spring Security @configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to have two security realms in spring usingconfiguration but I have not succeeded, I followed several online tutorials unsuccessfully closest I've come is to have the two security realms but could not run them both together

This is the code of my settings

Security Config:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MvcSecurityConfig Init");
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(301)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(302)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/signup", "/about").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Init Config

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfiguration.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        rootContext.register(WebSecurityConfig.class); 
        container.addFilter("rest-security-filter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/api/*");

        /*container.addFilter("mvc-security-filter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");*/
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate inner static classes into their own files (with annotation `@Configuration` on both and `@EnableWebSecurity` on second) and create another class which imports them:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter.class, FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class})
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

And register it onStartup `rootContext.register(SecurityConfig.class);`