# Separate authentication providers for two realms in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

We use the Spring MVC framework (incl. Spring Security) to implement both a web page and a REST web service. Both are supposed to support username/password authentication. However, they should implement two separate security realms with separate user databases.

The problem we're facing is that Spring security merges the two separate authentication providers into a single list of authentication providers and checks all username/password pairs against both providers. How can we have separate authentication providers for the two realms?

We have tried to separate the realms by using separate roles/authorities. However, if the credentials of the web pages are used to authenticate against the web service, it results in a 403 error (`Forbidden`) instead of a 401 error (`Unauthorized`). And since we have to keep perfect backward compatibility with pre-Spring implementation, this is a problem.

Furthermore, we've also tried to split the configuration into several non-inner classes (as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756938/413337). However, that didn't help either.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebServiceConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(new WebServiceUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/service/**")
                        .hasRole("SERVICE")
                    .and()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebPagesConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(new WebPagesUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider());
        }      

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

We have implemented a solution by creating a copy of the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` class and using them for the web service only. However, we would still prefer a solution without code duplication. Could the approach be to create separate authentication manager instances for the two realms?